# How to find the elementary divisors of this endomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to do the following exercise:

> Consider the endomorphism $h\colon\mathbb{R}^{6}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{6}$ with unique eigenvalues $0,\,2,\,8$. If $h$ is not diagonalizable and we know that dim$S(0)=1$, dim$S(2)\geq2$, dim$S(8)\geq2$, find all the possibilities for the elementary divisors and invariant factors.

I have read that if $a$ is an eigenvalue of $h$ and dim$S(a)=\lambda$, then there are $\lambda$ elementary divisors that are powers of $x-a$. Is this right? How can I continue the exercise?

Clarifications:

(1) By ''unique'' I mean that there are no other eigenvalues.

(2) $S(a)$ is the generalized eigenspace of $a$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think for the statement you have read to make sense, $S(a)$ should be the eigenspace, but with a correction "$\lambda$ elementary divisors *that are* powers of $x-a$". (There may be other elementary divisors too.) We're given that there are at least $5$ linearly independent eigenvectors. 6 can't be, so there is a single $2\times 2$ Jordan block, and the inequalities are actually equalities. Now you can consider three cases.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist So, for example, the elementary divisors could be: $\left\{x, x-2, x-2, x-2, x-8, x-8\right\}$ or $\left\{x, (x-2)^{2},\,(x-8)^{3}\right\}$? I ask this because I am not sure if the first case could be possible given that $h$ is not diagonalizable, or this has nothing to do with it?

Comment: If I am remembering the terminology correctly, the "elementary divisors" is the name given to the primary (=prime power here)

Comment: @JorgeRubio The first case is excluded exactly by the non-diagonalizable requirement. The number of elementary divisors of type $(x-a)^k$ is equal to the number of Jordan blocks with eigenvalue $a$ and equal to the number of (non-generalized) eigenvectors with this eigenvalue. After clarification (2), I think that there are more than three cases.

Answer (score 1):

If I am remembering the terminology correctly, the "elementary divisors" is the name given to the primary (="prime power" here) ideals that occur when representing $\mathbb R^6$ as a direct sum of cyclic $\mathbb R[t]$-modules (the primary decomposition has the maximal number of cyclic summands, while the description with the minimal number of cyclic summands is the one associated to the "invariant factors"). The constraints on the generalised eigenspaces means that $x$ occurs exactly once, and then you have

$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\dim(S(2))+\dim(S(8)) =5
$$
Thus if $\dim(S(2))=3$, then you can have $\{(x-2),(x-2),(x-2)\}$ or $\{x-2,(x-2)^2\}$ or $\{(x-2)^3\}$, and similarly for the eigenvalue $8$ -- though now by $(\dagger)$ $\dim(S(8)) = 2$ then you have two possibilities: $\{(x-8)^2\}$ or $\{(x-8),(x-8)\}$.